# Continuum Mechanics: Momentum Balance Equation of infinitesimal square

Tags: symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

**Introduction:**

According to the theory, the stress tensor should be symmetric. [On This page](https://www.continuummechanics.org/stressintroduction.html), and on many others, the explanation is: Taking the rotational equilibrium around the center of this 2D square yields, that tao_xy should be equal to tao_yx:

[image: src = https://www.continuummechanics.org/stressintroduction.html]

**I am confused by this:**

Why do we assume tao_xy on the right of the square to be equal to tao_xy on the left of the square? Couldn't it be different? Wouldn't this assumption make tao_xy and tao_yx equal and constant in throughout every point of the body?

**Furthermore:**

[In a different post](https://www.continuummechanics.org/equilibrium.html), they showed this figure:

[image: src = https://www.continuummechanics.org/equilibrium.html]

This picture is more understandable for me. As we can see, the right tao_xy differs from the left tao_yx. But given this circumstance, the proof for the symmetry of the stress tensor doesn't work anymore. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicates https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62963/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi. Check this short video.   https://www.coursera.org/learn/mechanics-1/lecture/8bkbv/module-5-general-state-of-stress-at-a-point-3d